# Can't publish custom type post - always stays at draft status

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type in my plugin:

```
$labels = array(
        'name' => __('Weekday message', 'weekmes'),
        'singular_name' => __('Weekday message', 'weekmes'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New', 'weekmes'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New message item', 'weekmes'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit message item', 'weekmes'),
        'new_item' => __('New message item', 'weekmes'),
        'all_items' => __('All message items', 'weekmes'),
        'view_item' => __('View message item', 'weekmes'),
        'search_items' => __('Search message item', 'weekmes'),
        'not_found' => __('No message item found', 'weekmes'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No message item found in the Trash', 'weekmes'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Weekday message',
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => 'weekmes custom post type',
        'public' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor'),
        'has_archive' => true,
    );
    register_post_type('weekmes', $args);
```

The problem is, that when i click puslish, it saves it as draft. When i try to edit it also saves as draft. Some screens for beeing clear:

[image: Saving new post]

[image: After saving]
[image: Editing saved post]

I am also adding one meta data, but I think it's not the problem:

```
function weekmesMetaboxContent($post) {
    wp_nonce_field(plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'weekmes_metabox_check_it');
    $post_meta_date = get_post_meta((!empty($post->ID) ? $post->ID : ''),     'weekmes_date', true);
    echo '<label for="weekmes_message_date"></label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="weekmes_message_date" name="weekmes_date"     value="' . (!empty($post_meta_date) ? $post_meta_date : date('Y-m-d')) . '" placeholder="' . __('Enter appearance date', 'weekmes') . '" readonly/><div class="weekmes-output" style="display:none"></div>';
}

function weekmesMetabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'weekmes_metabox',
        __('Appearance date', 'weekmes'),
        'weekmesMetaboxContent',
        null,
        'normal',
        'high'
    );
}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'weekmesMetabox');

function weekmesPostSave($post_id) {
    if (empty($_POST)) {
        return;
    }
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['weekmes_metabox_check_it'],     plugin_basename(__FILE__))) {
        return;
    }
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
            return;
        }
    }

    $message_date = isset($_POST['weekmes_date']) ? $_POST['weekmes_date'] : null;
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'weekmes_date', $message_date);
}

add_action('save_post', 'weekmesPostSave');
```

Does anybody have an idea how could i fix it? I know, i colud at save_post hook change post status of just saved post to "published" but it's not the "best practice" way.

Comment: Your Normal Posts are working fine did you check?
is there any use of following function on your theme please check.
function custom_post_status()

Comment: Check this solution too: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/182130/pages-are-not-saving-due-to-custom-post-type

Comment: @Xabby Other (i.e. default) post type works fine. I don't see this function in theme. Checked it with twenty seventeen, twenty sixteen, twenty fifteen. Also solution in linked question is not, what is causing the problem, anyway i am doing similar think by checking nonce.